# uncaught error "tablesorter is not a function", the function is not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Master page : i have used jquery 1.5 in master page and 1.7,1.8 in child page

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/hideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`enter code here`
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.equalHeight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
        }
    );
```

child page javascript: in this ADD function is not calling

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[id*=btnadd]").live("click", function () {
            debugger;
            $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                title: "Manage Branch",
                autoopen: false,
                width: 500,
                buttons: {
                    ADD: function () {
                        $("[id*=add]").click();
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });

            return false;
        });

 <div id="modal_dialog" style="display: none">
            <div class="tab_container">
                <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
                    <table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <b>ID:
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 130px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        Branch:
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 97px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                   <asp:Button ID="add" runat="server" Text="ADD" style="display:none" OnClick="btninsert_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </table>

                    <%--  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style = "display:none"  OnClick = "Button_Click"/>--%>

                </div>
                <!-- end of #tab1 -->
            </div>
            <!-- ID -->
        </div>
```

calling function:  when clicking the Add button this function has to call

```
protected void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=WINCTRL-TNT3FMR;Initial Catalog=TaxiAPP;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into Branch(ID,Branch)values(@ID,@Branch)SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con);
        con.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", TextBox2.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please format you code first. And let me tell you, `.live()` is not supporting in jquery. Instead of `.live()` you can use `.on()` method.

Comment: .on()  method is also not working

Comment: I think you have missed end `<script>` tag in you code.

Comment: sorry i didnt pasted here .. have included that </script>  in my codings either it is not working??

Answer (score 0):

Please replace these 2 code and try, Hope this will work,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
    });
 </script>
```

And,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnadd]", function () {
            debugger;
            $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                title: "Manage Branch",
                autoopen: false,
                width: 500,
                buttons: {
                    ADD: function () {
                        $("[id*=add]").click();
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });

            return false;
        });
</script>
```

Comment: is there any problems when i use different jquery version codings in Master page and child page???

Comment: Is your Jqery library from Master page is loading in child page as well?

Comment: Master page jquery:

Comment: yes...it is working but only the error is tablesorter and the function is not calling..

Comment: And the function is not calling

Comment: What is the error? And are you refering proper id in script?

Comment: `"[id*=btnadd]"` Which element is this?

Comment: Button Add: function ()

Comment: samir are you there??